# Remove non static span class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm generating a span tag in the following way:

```
var clss = $(this).attr("dclss");
<span id="'+id+'" dtype = "'+type+'" dclss="'+clss+'" dattr="'+attr+'" class=" anyi '+clss+'"></span>
```

When i click on this span, his class is changing to "active". After that when i click on the other span i want to remove this active class, but not sure how.I've tried this:

```
$(".selected .content").on('click','.close-icon', function(){
     var clss = $(this).attr("dclss");
     $(this).closest('.liveicon').fadeOut(500);
     $("#anyi " + clss ).removeClass("active");
 });
```

But i got class undefined. Any ideas how to get the span class with jQuery ?

HTML:

```
str += '<div class="liveicon" id="'+id+'" dtype = "'+type+'" dclss="'+clss+'" dattr="'+attr+'">';
str += '<span class="close-icon" id="close-icon">&#10006;</span>';
str += '<span id="'+id+'" dtype = "'+type+'" dclss="'+clss+'" dattr="'+attr+'" class=" anyi '+clss+'"></span>';
str += '<div class="clearboth"></div>';
str += '<div class="codes">';
str += '<div class="tit">FONT</div><input type="text" class="fontsc" value="[anyicon i=\''+clss+'\' '+stylestr+']">';
str += '<div class="tit">PNG</div><input type="text" class="pngsc" value="[anyicon i=\''+clss+'\' '+stylestr+' type=\'png\']">';
str += '<div class="tit">SVG</div><input type="text" class="svgsc" value="[anyicon i=\''+clss+'\' '+stylestr+' type=\'svg\']">';
str += '</div>';
str += '</div>';
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: Why, i just want to get the span class dynamically

Comment: At-least add your html so that we can come to know where close icon exist and where span exist?

Comment: You should never ask yourself "Why provide a fiddle?". If you can, do it. It helps a lot!

Comment: I've added html

Comment: @Rumen that is because `<span class="close-icon" id="close-icon">&#10006;</span>` does not have any attribute as dclss so `var clss = $(this).attr("dclss");` is undefined

Comment: @Rumen  you have to create a working fiddle example otherwise no-one can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

"dclss" isn't a valid html attribute, so that may be causing the issue. In general, for custom attributes, you should use the "data-" prefix, so try it with "data-previous-class".

Another approach is to use the attribute instead of a CSS class, so just do $(this).attr("data-is-active", "false") and $(this).attr("data-is-active", "true"). You can write a css selector like this:

```
span[data-is-active="false"] {
   //inactive CSS
}

span[data-is-active="true"] {
   //active CSS
}
```